# Validation on EditText in ListView Adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-adapter

I have a ListView Adapter as below coding:

```
@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup){
    if(layoutInflater == null){
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    if(view == null){
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_pickingscan, null);
    }

    final TextView tvMaterialCode = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_picking_scan_materialcode_tv);
    EditText etSerialNumber = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.list_picking_scan_serialnumber_tv);

    final PickingDetails pickingDetails = pickingDetailsList.get(i);
    tvMaterialCode.setText(pickingDetails.getMaterialCode().toString());
    etSerialNumber.setText(pickingDetails.getSerialNumber().toString());
    etSerialNumber.setMaxLines(1);
    return view;
}
}
```

The View should be as below:

```
Material Code    Serial Number
Material A       ______________
Material B       ______________
```

I want to do a validation on EditText Serial number every time user input the value before submit button. How to make it?

Answer (score 2):

You can add validation using **TextWatcher**

```
 private class GenericTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;

    private GenericTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case **First View Id:**
            //validation for first edit text
            break;
            case **second view id :**
            //validation for second edit text
             break
        }

    }
}

m_InputMobile.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(m_InputMobile));
secondView.addTextChangedListener(new GenericTextWatcher(secondView));
```

Comment: how can i know which editText or editText of Position was selected as per your answer?

Comment: Okay let me update the answer for multiple editTexts

Comment: but again my question is same how did you know which edittext is selected on which position?
**Suppose you select**
editText  from 1  position 
then you select 2 position
how did you know which editText is selected based on position

Comment: Yup. How to know EditText position?

Comment: As you are passing the reference of view to GenericTextWatcher when creating the object for every edit text. So, you can get the id of the view for which the object of GenericTextWatcher is executed like this

 **switch (view.getId()){
            case **First View Id:**
            //validation for first edit text
            break;
            case **second view id :**
            //validation for second edit text
             break
        }**

Comment: @Sunny did you check your updated answer is working?

Comment: @Arbaz.in Yes, I am using it in my project.

Comment: @Sunny how to get value of the EditText? As example, current active EditText is at row 1, how to get value of EditText at row 1?

Comment: @user2412351 If you are using it in the recycler view then you have to pass the position and then you can check the value for row 1